# add substring to column if string in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to manipulate a csv file with a series of dates which inconsistently use 'CE' and 'BCE' in one column or the other. Imagine a condensed example:

```
 ID,earliestdate, latestdate
 1,1st century, 2nd century CE
 2,3rd century, 2nd century BCE
```

How could I write a function that would join 'CE' to df['earliestdate'] if 'CE' in df['latestdate']?

Comment: _dates which inconsistently use 'CE' and 'BCE'_ how do you know they're used inconsistently? `CE` does not equal `BCE`. In fact, the dates look they way they should. 1st century to 2nd century should be CE or common era, where as 3rd century to 2nd century should be BCE or before the common era.

Comment: BCE and CE are alternatives to the Dionysian BC and AD system respectively.

Comment: Additionally, how do you know, that in rows where the latest date is CE, that the earliest date isn't BCE? For `ID 1`, the earlies date could be `1st century BCE`. The only thing you can know for certain is that if the latest date is BCE then the earliest date must also be BCE.

Comment: For context, I split a column that contained a series of strings in the format '1st-2nd century CE' which ordinarily would mean '1st century CE -- 2nd century CE' and I was trying to parse the 1st to read 1st century CE. Is there a way to spell that out when splitting a column?

Comment: Then that should work. I think the solution by intermezzio works for your request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas indexing to check which rows have 'CE' in them and add 'CE' to the corresponding 'earliestdate' strings.

```py
df.loc[df["latestdate"].str.endswith(" CE"), "earliestdate"] = \
    df.loc[df["latestdate"].str.endswith(" CE"), "earliestdate"].astype(str) +\
    " CE"
```